# Unable to use coroutines in Kotlin (unresolved reference)

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I created gradle java kotlin project. I want to use coroutines but I get `unresolved reference launch` and `unresolved reference delay` errors:

```
import java.util.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

fun main (args: Array<String>)
{
    launch { // launch coroutine 
        delay(1000L) 
        println("World!")
    }
    println("Hello")
}
```

In build.gradle.kts I included this line in dependencies block:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")
```

EDIT:

My build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"
    java
}

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.6.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2")
}

tasks.getByName<Test>("test") {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

EDIT2:
Everything fixed after clearing cache. You can do it in File->Invalidate caches

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `runBlocking` here, otherwise there won't be a *Coroutine Scope* where you could call `launch` and `delay`.

Working example very similar to yours (taken from [*your first coroutine*](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coroutines-basics.html#your-first-coroutine)):

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking { // this: CoroutineScope
    launch { // launch a new coroutine and continue
        delay(1000L) // non-blocking delay for 1 second (default time unit is ms)
        println("World!") // print after delay
    }
    println("Hello") // main coroutine continues while a previous one is delayed
}
```

Output (as expected):

```
Hello
World!
```

### EDIT:

If you still experience error messages of the form *Unresolved reference: …*,
you can try to fix the `implementation` in your `gradle.build.kts` from the one you posted in your question,

```gradle
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx", "kotlinx-coroutines-core", "1.5.2")
```

to this:

```gradle
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2")
```

and try again. Hope that helps…

Comment: It is the same. Unresolved reference runBlocking @deHaar

Comment: @vytaute See my edit, I don't think the Kotlin code is wrong, so I guess it's the gradle import of the coroutines.

Comment: I tried to implement your suggestion but it still does not work... I get same error. I added build.gradle.kts file for you to see

Comment: Just a guess: In your `build.gradle.kts` you have `kotlin("jvm") version "1.5.10"` but also the `kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.5.2`, which might be a version mismatch (kotlin version is below coroutines version). But I'm not sure if that is really the issue or an issue at all. I would try to use kotlin 1.5.31, for example @vytaute

Comment: no, it did not help. Thank you for your support anyway. But I am completely lost, how do people write project in Kotlin with coroutines then if literally nothing works 5th day in a row...

Comment: Very sorry for that… It must have something to do with the library import (the keywords are not abailable in your code), maybe try to set up the same project with maven or even try to clean the project and ide caches.

Comment: Clearing cache did helped! Thank you so much!

Comment: Cool, glad it helped!